# Random messages algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, random, parse-platform

So I'm making an iOS app where users can send/receive messages to/from other random user but I'm trying to figure out what will be the most efficient way to implement it with these conditions and using Parse.com:

- If user hasn't received any message for 24 hours automatically retrieve one from the server
- The user has more possibilities of receive a message for each message he sends

I was thinking on do it this way:

1 - Making a new class "X" where users are added once they have sent a message, this message will be sent to a user already in that class "X" and the user will be removed from the class once he received it.

2 - To make the user receive a message every 24 hours - Set a portion of code that is executed every 24hours and adds the user to class "X" so he has the possibility to receive a message.

So the questions are:

- ¿Is there any other way more efficient than this one?
- ¿What can I use to set a portion of code to be executed every 24 hours? I've googled for a while but I only find solutions related to push notifications.

Comment: Sounds good... What the problem? You haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: Edited! Thank you Lynsdsey, I didn't notice it had no sense without a question.

Comment: "I've googled for a while but I only find solutions related to push notifications" -- why not use a push notification to trigger your code?

Comment: You mean like using a localnotification that triggers every 24 hours?

Comment: You could trigger a push notification every 24 hours by scheduling a background job with Parse's Cloud Code.

Comment: I see, I'll have to take a look at Parse's Cloud Code docs though since I haven't played with it yet.